# Suzuki swift 2011 p0403 with current malfunction error

Tags: suzuki, cel, egr, swift

Suzuki swift 2011 have p0403 with current malfunction error, all 6 wires are working fine and i replaced egr valve also. But still showing p0403 and engine have small missing on slow running.
How to resolve the problem?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Wanna know why showing error when wires are working fine and egr valve also replaced. How to resolve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Stupid question on my part, but did you clear the codes?

Comment: Thanks for appreciation for a new member, my mechanic clear the code. Also reset ecu by unplug the wires from battery.

Comment: Resolved by replacing the wires completely.